# What is the best way to encode parameters in website link

Tags: java, php, android, ios, encryption

What is the best way to encode and decode parameters in website link?

I need encode user id by android or ios system and send this parametr to PHP server.

For example: `www.example.com/getData.php?uid=[encode id]`

> Mobiles -> encode
>  Server -> decode

I am looking for a good algorithm for all platforms (Android, iOS and PHP).

Comment: use Base64 and which is available in the android library.

Comment: Why would you need to encode it specifically? Using ?uid=123456 works just fine.

Comment: Sounds like `Security by Obscurity`. Not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

#### Don't Do This:

[image: Don't encrypt URL parameters.]

#### Do This Instead:

[image: Use randomly generated IDs instead.]